# Can not install relational algebra interpreter writen in Java

Tags: java, sqlite, jar

RA is a simple relational algebra interpreter written in Java.
RA is packaged with SQLiteJDBC, so one can use RA as a standalone relational-algebra database system.
I downloaded the zip file and extracted the contents in a folder. According to the instructions the next step should be: "To run RA, just type "java -jar ra.jar" in the directory containing ra.jar. RA will then by default run on the SQLite database file sample.db (on which query examples below are based).".

I opened the Windows commander (I run Windows 10) and typed in the directory that contained ra.jar, java -jar ra.jar and pressed enter.  I received an error message:

```
 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable   program or batch file.
```

Can you help me?

Comment: do you have java installed? is its bin dir in your system %PATH?

Comment: Step 0: Install Java.

Comment: This Topic in the Java Language Documentation explains how to install and set up Java.  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/4754/installing-java-standard-edition#t=201610042237423642372

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed JAVA on your machine. If you have, check if path to your `JAVA_HOME` it is present in `%PATH%`.
You can see PATH variable by

`echo %PATH%`